# why password_verify returns false for correct password?

Tags: php

I have saved the hashed password in the database and want to compare it with the user input and every time it returns `false`, like in the image below.

What's going wrong?

[image]

Comment: please read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: we really need to see your actual code if we are going to be able to help you

Comment: Also, what image?

Comment: looks like your store the password in the databases a plane text. A. you cant use password_verify on that, B. please don't

Comment: I agree with @smith. You said you saved the hashed password, but `123` doesn't look hashed.

Comment: Someone hasn't saved the hashed password like they claimed. What comes out of the db should have echo'ed like: `$2y$10$Cx1g4z9w3z2nQ6FtTjGLDerVy3mbDb0j4jsjinTxk6h28a/vhXw1G` YMMV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if answering is a good idea .. but ill try

To use `password_verify` you must have a hashsed version of the users password (usully in a db). you compare the plain text version with the hashed version

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

to create the original hash which you store you use:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

in your code (which you shouldn't use) you are just comparing 2 strings so

```
if($password==$row['password']){
echo "matched";
}
```

is all that is required.

**super uber reference: [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords?rq=1)**